# Get email from shipping adrdress in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a website where we sell digital products.

For requirement when the buyer ask to send the license to another email the buyer uses shipping address to enter the extra email.

so I added the email with the following function.

```
/*
 * Add email to "shipping address"  
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

 // Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
 function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_email'] = array(
 'label'     => __('Email Address', 'woocommerce'),
 'placeholder'   => _x('Email', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
 'required'  => true,
 'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
 'clear'     => true
  );

  return $fields;
}
```

The shipping form displays properly the email on the shipping section, but when order is completed I'm trying to catch that email and I haven't had it.

I'm using the following function to add the email to the recipient before the email is sent.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'my_email_shipping_filter_function', 20, 2);

function my_email_shipping_filter_function ($recipient, $order){
$shipping_email = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_email', true );

if ($shipping_email != '') {
        $recipient = $recipient.', '.$shipping_email;
        return $recipient;
}
}
```

But it is not working when the confirmation is sent, however when Im redirected to thank you page I can use the same function and display the shipping email.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: check it out `$order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_email'][0]`

Comment: In the filter code, try setting `$shipping_email` to a hard coded email address instead of pulling it from post meta. If doing that works and you get an email sent, you know where the issue lies. :)

Comment: Thanks Fresher it didn't work, I get in my customer order Notice: 

Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/hectorc/sites/new/hecervdev/wp-content/themes/hecerv/functions.php on line 510

Comment: Anand I tried that as the first approach and that works but the thing is Im not catching the dynamic email